# pros and cons of having different servers/ports for client and server in MVC(node)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, model-view-controller

I am using MVC architecture.My Question what are the advantages and dis advantages in running client and server in different ports or different servers

Comment: The question is very unclear. First, you use MVC at the client or at the server? Then, client and server usually run on different machines, depending on what the "client" is, it can even be a web browser on somebody's machine far, far away from your server. Could you then narrow your question somehow to focus on what you are really into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question refers to the separate development of two different aspects of the application and these are: the backend API and the front-end. Its more of an architectural choice

Having APIs built separately from UIs, achieves:

- Less coupling. This way one can expand/upgrade/enhance both apps independently and flexibly, that too in different technologies.
- Extending the above point, APIs also provide the option of universal connectivity from various consuming clients such as mobile/web/IoT thereby giving the developer greater ingress across the spectrum. This helps in gaining business advantages over the competitors
- Complex business processes can also be composed by way of stitching together (orchestrating) atomic API endpoints
- Security: Putting everything up into one client facing application, including backend functionality raises obvious security red flags.
- Scalability: Both the apps (UI and API) can be scaled independently and elastically depending on their usage

One obvious drawback, if you will, is the "overhead" associated with the separate implementation of both sides and it can be an overkill if the use case is quite simple and the potential consumers of the app's functionality are quite less and its meant to be used/accessed in a secure environment (let's say on the internal network in a given corporate).

Like all design considerations, the above are also circumstantial as there is no one silver bullet but at the very least these are some considerations on which the design of the given app depends on.

HTH